# sending multiple keyevent using adb shell

Tags: android

I want to send multiple keyevent using adb.

After googleing I can to know about `adb shell input keyevent 65` but using this command I can send only one keyevent.

I want to simulate like " SHIFT_KEY + special character".

Answer (score -1):

Sample :

adb shell input keyevent 22 66 
means : press Send and press Enter